# SymetricWebServer doesnt create SYM* tables in embedded mode (Spring Boot)

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, symmetricds

I have a master server node (called root) deployed with standalone install archive and launched with "sym" command line on my machine and on a MySQL DB. => OK.

For my client server nodes, I try to use embedded SymmetricDS in Spring Boot within H2 file DB. (for a desktop application)
(I'm using SymmetricDS 3.12.5)

Here is my Spring boot code :

```
@Configuration
public class SymDSModule implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {

    @Autowired
    ServletContext servletContext;

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    final public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
        SymmetricEngineHolder holder = new SymmetricEngineHolder();
        File propFile = null;
        try {
            propFile = new ClassPathResource(
                    "symmetric-client.properties").getFile();
            Properties propertiesFile = new Properties();
            propertiesFile.load(new FileReader(propFile));

            ServerSymmetricEngine serverEngine = new ServerSymmetricEngine(dataSource, applicationContext, propertiesFile, false, holder);
            serverEngine.setDeploymentType("server");
            System.out.println(serverEngine.getDeploymentType());
            holder.getEngines().put(propertiesFile.getProperty(ParameterConstants.EXTERNAL_ID), serverEngine);
            //holder.setAutoStart(false);
            servletContext.setAttribute(WebConstants.ATTR_ENGINE_HOLDER, holder);

            serverEngine.setup();
            serverEngine.openRegistration("store", "002");
            serverEngine.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean<SymmetricServlet> symServlet() {
        ServletRegistrationBean<SymmetricServlet> bean = new ServletRegistrationBean<>(new SymmetricServlet(), "/sync");
        bean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

symmetric-client.properties:

```
engine.name=store-002
db.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.url=jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9090/~/mydb;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=60000
db.user=****
db.password=****
registration.url=http://localhost:31415/sync/root-000
group.id=store
external.id=002
job.routing.period.time.ms=5000
job.push.period.time.ms=10000
job.pull.period.time.ms=10000
auto.registration=true
initial.load.create.first=true
auto.config.database=true
start.refresh.cache.job=true
auto.sync.triggers=true
auto.reload = true;
https.verified.server.names=all
```

application.yml file :

```
spring:
  application:
    name: myapp
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
      properties:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        search:
          default:
            directory_provider: filesystem
            indexBase: data/indexes/local/main
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    url: jdbc:h2:/~/mydb;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    username: username
    password: password
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
server:
  port: 8183
```

At the first launch of my app, SymetricWebServer does not create the SYM* tables in serverEngine.setup() step, as I expected.

> --- [  restartedMain] o.j.symmetric.AbstractSymmetricEngine    : Initializing SymmetricDS database
>
> --- [  restartedMain] o.j.symmetric.db.h2.H2SymmetricDialect   : Checking if SymmetricDS tables need created or altered
>
> --- [  restartedMain] o.j.s.service.impl.ConfigurationService  : Auto-configuring config channel
>
> --- [restartedMain] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
> org.jumpmind.db.sql.SqlException: Table "SYM_CHANNEL" not found
> Table "SYM_CHANNEL" not found; SQL statement

I try to create the symmetric tables in client H2 database with standalone symmetric installation command, then restart my Spring boot app. After that, everything is OK for sync with master node in Spring boot application...

Does embedded SymetricWebServer is able to create automaticaly SYM* tables (if they not exist) on my client H2 database at the first Spring boot execution ?

Did I miss something ?

Comment: Could you try using the H2 database in file mode instead just to eliminate that as the issue?

jdbc:h2:file:databasename;LOCK_TIMEOUT=60000;WRITE_DELAY=0

Comment: Edit: I shared my application.yml file

Comment: I tired to modify jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto value just in case, but no effect

Comment: Hi Josh, Thank you for your help. I tried this morning to put db.url=jdbc:h2:file:./mydb;LOCK_TIMEOUT=60000;WRITE_DELAY=0 both in my symmetric.ds property file and application.yml, but SYM tables are still not created

Comment: does this work when you don't run symmetric in embedded mode?